# Check box and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I'm trying to create a module wherein whenever a checkbox is checked the price indicated in the database will be added to the total charges and the result will be shown. How do I get the value from the database(sql)/insert the php code and show the result of the chosen boxes?

```
<script>
function updateTextArea() { 
    var allVals = [];
    $('#c_b :checked').each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#t').val(allVals)
}
$(function() {
    $('#c_b input').click(updateTextArea);
    updateTextArea();
});
```

index.php

```
$queryPaymentLab = "select * from requestedlab where patient_ID='6' AND paid='0'";
$resultPaymentLab = mysql_query($queryPaymentLab);
$countRowsPaymentLab=mysql_num_rows($resultPaymentLab);

if($countRowsPaymentLab > 0){
while($fetchLab=mysql_fetch_array($resultPaymentLab)){
    $labservice_ID=$fetchLab['labservice_ID'];

    $queryPrice = "select * from labservices where labservice_ID='".$labservice_ID."'";
    $resultPrice = mysql_query($queryPrice);
    $fetchPrice=mysql_fetch_array($resultPrice);

    $labService=$fetchPrice['labService'];
    $labPrice=$fetchPrice['labPrice'];
    $totalLab+=$labPrice;
    $totalHBill+=$labPrice;

    echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='labservice_ID' value='$labservice_ID'/></td>
    <td>Laboratory</td><td>$labService</td><td>$totalHBill</td></tr>";
}
}
```

To show the total charges..

```
 $queryPrice = "select * from labservices where labservice_ID='".$labservice_ID."'";
    $resultPrice = mysql_query($queryPrice);

    while($fetchPrice=mysql_fetch_array($resultPrice)){   
        $labPrice=$fetchPrice['labPrice'];
        $total+=$labPrice;
    }

    echo "<strong>Total:</strong>
    <strong>$total</strong>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using the HTML5 `data` attribute?

HTML:

```
<?php 
// Use PHP to dynamically fetch the data-price values and generate the HTML below
?>
<span class="item" data-price="100">...</span>
<span class="item" data-price="90">...</span>
<span class="item" data-price="130">...</span>

USD: <span class="price">0</span>
```

JS:

```
function updateCost() {
    $('.item').each(
        function() {
            if ($(this).children('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                var oldPrice = parseInt($('.price').text());
                var newPrice = oldPrice + parseInt($(this).data('price'));
                $('.price').text(newPrice);
            }
        }
    );
 }
```

- Call `updateCost()` in the `onchange` event for each checkbox
- Make sure unselecting a checkbox subtracts the price from total price appropriately!
- **Don't forget to total up and check prices on submit, since you are prone to fraudulent purchases otherwise!**

This way you avoid unnecessary Ajax and the code stays cleaner. Sorry if this isn't what you wanted, let me know so I can help better.

In case you're having some sort of market place where the costs themselves are updating real-time this would need some external help. For a market-place, simply call an Ajax function that updates the `data-price` attributes for each item appropriately! :)